# Error on Void with Alamofire and PromiseKit with Swift (Request)

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, promisekit, alamofire-request

n my last projects I have been using  alamofire and promisekit to connect to my web services Now I have a new version of both and when I create a request I get this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'DataRequest' to closure result type 'Void'
```

this happens when I try to do this:

```
func CallOne() -> Promise<[String: AnyObject]>{
        return Promise{
            fullfil,reject -> Void in
            return Alamofire.request(
                url_api,
                method: .get).responseJSON{
                    response in
                    switch(response.result){
                    case .success(let res):
                        let data = res as? [String: AnyObject]
                        fullfil(data!)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        reject(error)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

and when I try to use this:

```
func CallTwo(email: String, phone: String) -> Promise<[String: AnyObject]>{
    let params =
        ["email": email, "phone": phone]
    return Promise{
        fullfil,reject -> Void in
        return Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
                for (key, value) in params {
                    MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, to: url_api, method: .post) { (result) in
            switch (result){
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    switch(response.result){
                    case .success(let res):
                        let data = res as? [String: AnyObject]
                        fullfil(data!)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        reject(error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error `Unable to infer closure type in the current context`

How can I solve that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this using

> seal in

```
func CallOne() -> Promise<[String: AnyObject]>{
    return Promise{
        seal in
        return Alamofire.request(
            url_api,
            method: .get).responseJSON{
                response in
                switch(response.result){
                case .success(let res):
                    let data = res as? [String: AnyObject]
                    seal.fulfill(data!)
                case .failure(let error):
                    seal.reject(error)
                }
        }
    }
}

func CallTwo(email: String, phone: String) -> Promise<[String: AnyObject]>{
    let params =
        ["email": email, "phone": phone]
    return Promise{
        seal in
        return Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
                for (key, value) in params {
                    MultipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, to: url_api, method: .post) { (result) in
            switch (result){
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    switch(response.result){
                    case .success(let res):
                        let data = res as? [String: AnyObject]
                        seal.fulfill(data!)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        seal.reject(error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```